# Clarification on Docker for Windows install

Tags: docker-for-windows

I'm confused by the Docker for Windows install instructions at https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/

The instructions state:

"*Containers and images created with Docker Desktop are shared between all user accounts* on machines where it is installed. This is because all Windows accounts use the same VM to build and run containers." => This makes sense.

However this seems to be contradicted in the next sentence:

"Note that it is *not possible to share containers and images between user accounts* when using the Docker Desktop WSL 2 backend." => Do they mean if you use Docker within the WSL, then containers/images can't be shared between users? (as opposed to using the Docker for Windows which then uses WSL under the covers)?

Thanks for any clarifications/confirmations.

Comment: the way I'm reading it, is that its not possible to share it between windows users, when WSL is used for the backend. this kinda makes sense to me because WSL (and I'm no expert on it) stores the virtual disks for its instance in the owning users %APPDATA% directory. contents in that directory cannot be easily accessed by other users, but the bigger problem is that APPDATA is establisehd as a VFS location within the filesystem, and the Docker programmers used appropriate references to the executing users APPDATA location, so userX can't use userY's APPDATA without conflict.

Comment: That does seem like it would explain it. Maybe just badly written? It's in the WSL installation section, but it seems like the information effectively says "These images are shared between all users.  Note these images are not shared between all users."  Could do with a re-write.